# Serial EEPROM with FAT

Tags: serial, eeprom

Is it possible to format an SPI EEPROM (such as AT24C128) to be used as an SD card?
So format it with FAT 32 and have a 16MB drive appear in windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you'd need some kind of controller, you couldn't just wire the eeprom directly. This is because the EEPROM does not speak SD card protocol. I would probably bypass SD completely, and just use USB. So something like:

```
SPI EEPROM <-SPI-> AVR <-USB-> PC
```

Look into the examples provided with the AVR USB library, [Lufa](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php), one of the examples shows exactly the above setup...except it's using an Atmel DataFlash instead of a SPI EEPROM. But it's possible, you'd just need to change the code which accesses the Flash to instead access the EEPROM.

Answer (score 2):

Microchip also has an example of how to implement a USB mass storage device.

[AN1189 - Implementing a Mass Storage Device](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en536602)

Comment: Link rotted. Here's a new one for AN1189: [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01189a.pdf)